# Can I Use two ApplicationUser contexts for same application log in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile, azure, asp.net-identity

My question involves both a technical and a modeling issue.

I have a MCV 5 system where there will be a web front-end and also a mobile app(Android).
At some point the web user will be able to see a queue of mobile signed-on users.
Mobile accounts wont access web front-end neither web accounts the mobile app.
I have chosen Azure to provide all my system needs.

Modeling wise, should I create separate login systems(one more backend system for mobile login)?

If not, is the Asp.net Identity system capable of using two different logins, as I tought roughly something like this:

```
namespace Application.Models {
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationMobileClient> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationMobileClient : IdentityUser
{

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

}

The web user model would have a collection of mobile clients model. Just like an photo/comments system. But I dont know(well I asume not) if the Identity can do something like this, handle two logins on same application. I could Maybe im just larning too much technologies/frameworks/metodologies/patters at the same time and Im just dont know what to do lol.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you should need **two different ApplicationUser**. Because it's the **same user** regardless if he is on your website or signed in through your Android app. If you want to **keep track** of the users mobile sign ins then you can add a property to the ApplicationUser.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<MobileSignIn> MobileSignIns { get; set; }
}

public class MobileSignIn
{

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
}
```